# When I left click my G900 it act like forward button

Tags: mouse

As title says, when I left click my mouse button the action is the same of a forward button click. It happens everywhere, in the browsers or in Explorer.

The configuration in the Logitech software seems fine, so it's probably a Windows problem, or driver problem. EDIT: I'm on Windows 10 Pro N 1607

I searched but found nothing similar and I really can't understand what is going on.

EDIT: I tried with another machine and the mouse have the same problem.

SOLVED: I uninstalled and reinstalled the Logitech Software

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 Pro N 1607

Comment: Do you have another machine to try the mouse on?

Comment: What do you mean by "forward" button?  Do you mean up/down arrow?  Or page forward, like with Alt-Right Arrow?

Comment: @Paul I mean page forward. Some mice have dedicated buttons for it. It's the equivalent of alt+right arrow.

Comment: @wysiwyg Tried with my laptop. Same problem. It's a mouse problem then

Comment: The G900 is a programmable mouse. You will need to connect it to a computer with the Logitech software to reprogram it to default values.

Comment: @music2myear The configuration in the Logitech software seems fine, so it's probably a Windows problem, or driver problem.

Comment: Considering you get the same problem on two different computers I would say it is exceptionally unlikely the problem is with the "driver" or Windows. One way to be further certain is to try a different mouse on both of these computers. If the Left-Click on that mouse has the SAME problem, then yes, it's likely a Windows issue, but if not, the issue is limited to the mouse. Also, you only say the mouse config "seems fine". Did you check the bindings? Did you try re-binding the mouse keys to the correct or default modes?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by just uninstalling and reinstalling the Logitech Software